# How do I override the ReadOnly property on DevExpress editors with repositoryitems

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I use Delphi XE3 and DevExpress ExpressEditors Library 12.2.4.

I have a form with several DevExpress editors (TcxTextEdit, TcxLookupCombobox, TcxImageComboBox, TcxMemo and TcxPopupEdit among others). Many of these editors (but not all) have a repositoryitem. I need to set some of these editors to readonly. If i do this

```
Edit1.Properties.ReadOnly := true;
```

it will not work if the editor has a repositoryitem, since the repositoryitems value will override the editors properties. If I do this

```
Edit1.ActiveProperties.ReadOnly := true;
```

this will actually change the repositoryitem, so all editors based on the same repositoryitem will also be readonly.

One solution I tried was to assign the repositoryitems properties to the editors properties before showing the form, and set the repositoryitem to nil. This worked fine for the ReadOnly property, but had the side effect that this also set the editor events to the repositoryitems events. Many of the editors on the form has events, so I couldn't use this solution. One solution to this would be to manually reset the OnXXX-properties after clearing the repositoryitem, but I also have a few editors that have events both on the editor and on the associated repositoryitem.

How do I set the readonly property of some of the editors, but not on other editors that use the same repositoryitem? I would love a solution that worked on all properties, but for now ReadOnly is most important.

Comment: It's always good to give the actual class of this mystery edit1 control. (`TcxEdit`?)  Don't make people guess.

Comment: There are several editors, mostly derived from TcxCustomEdit. I believe most of DevExpress' editors work in a similar way when it comes to repositoryitems, but for completeness' sake, I need a solution for TcxTextEdit, TcxLookupCombobox, TcxCalcEdit, TcxImageComboBox, TcxMemo and TcxPopupEdit :-)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question.
As far as I know there are two ways.

1. Handle the `ShowingEditor` event and using e.Cancel if this is supposed to be read only.
2. Create two repository items, one set to `ReadOnly`, and assign them to the different controls respectively.